# oracle + java encoding problem while insert

Tags: java, oracle, encoding

I am kind of stuck on this one. im not a java or oracle guru, so please give detailed answers :)

i've a web-service that inserts something into DB. the web-service is hosted on axis. the db is oracle with following properties:

```
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_CHARACTERSET    ZHS16GBK
```

the web-service is hosted on windows server 2008, english version but i have changed the locale of the system to chinese

now the data after insert has encoding problem and shows strange characters like ????,exxk??

the jws file has GBK encoding. and the data that is inserted into the DB is hard-coded in the file [we are not reading it from REQUEST]

[edit]
just one thing, its not feasible to change the whole DB to utf-8 as it has lots of table and data

[further edit] to make things more clear

the machine accepts data from two source. basically it is being used to send and receive sms/mms to our subscribed users. primarily, it operates with the GSM operator control center where all encodings are handled in GBK. On the other hand, the machine also accepts requests from the website to send sms/mms to the users. Here the encoding are handled in UTF-8. If the website wants to send a sms to the user, it will invoke a web-service on this machine which will insert data into db[our problem is here]. then a windows service continously checks the DB and if it finds any new request to send sms/mms, it will send the sms/mms and delete the record.

everything was working fine on the old machine as it had chinese version of windows 2003. we upgraded to a new server and installed windows 2008 server english version on it. and now the data is distorted after the web-service inserts into DB.

Comment: Can you better show the whole processing pipeline from where the data is coming, to where it's processed, to where it's stored and finally to how it's examined. I don't quite see what the role of the web service is. Can you tell us at which point in the pipeline the data is still okay? I doubt that the insert itself is the problem because both Java and Oracle know about encodings and characters sets and they complain if they cannot convert it.

Answer (score 1):

Make the characterset to UTF8.

Comment: it isnt a feasible option.. coz there are too many tables and too much data... any tools to automate it?

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend choosing UTF8 as the database charset.

Beware though, since by default java uses UTF16 encoding.
To set the default encoding used by java, use the 'file.encoding' flag:

java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 ...

I never heard about the ZHS16GBK charset but it doesn't seem to be supported by java:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html

Comment: @arnaud - Java always uses UTF-16 strings and setting `file.encoding` (which should never be done) will not change this; the default transcoding encoding for I/O is platform dependent. ZHS16GBK is simplified Chinese and it is supported by Java. Using UTF-8 is something I would agree with.

Comment: @McDowell - well, if you want to correctly read/write UTF-8 from files, sockets and so on, that's the most straightforward way to do it. Out of curiosity, why would it bad? ...yeah, well, except if you wanna handle many types of encoding at once which is a pain in the ... ...and why does ZHS16GBK not appear in the list of supported encodings then?

Comment: @arnaud - RE `file.encoding`: _The "file.encoding" property is not required by the J2SE platform specification; it's an internal detail of Sun's implementations and should not be examined or modified by user code. It's also intended to be read-only; it's technically impossible to support the setting of this property to arbitrary values on the command line or at any other time during program execution._ http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4163515 You can do it; you might get lucky.

Comment: @arnaud - RE ZHS16GBK: this is "GBK" in Java. However, the JDBC driver should be taking care of the transcoding operations; I suspect there original poster's problem lies somewhere else - perhaps trying to store code points not supported by GBK - there isn't enough information to tell.

Comment: well.. sorry for later reply.. i was out of office.  first thing is that we have lots of data in our DB and converting all of it to UTF-8 doesn't seem like a feasible option. the problem is like this . we have a query insert into t1 (col1,col2) values ("abcd","你好“）[col2 has chinese characters]. now these characters are hard-coded into the java code. why we are still having this problem?

Comment: also. the problem is that same code was running on a machine with windows server 2003 [chinese version] and it never had any problems. the new machine [windows server 2008] does support chinese and GBK charset