# Charset difference using JPA but not with prepared statement

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa, character-encoding

I have a application using spring boot + oracle (via tomcat datasource). Using spring-data, a simple query in a table returns characters with encoding problem.

This same application, in a very specific situation, creates a *ad hoc* connection (without datasource) using JDBC and execute a query in the same table. But in this case there is no problem with the encoding.

Obs.: Firstly, I thought it was just a web (front-end) problem (some JS component), but verifying the HTTP response on browser, the data is already with problem in the first case, but not in the second.

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I could not find something similar. I know there are a lot of oracle+java+charset issues, but my problem differs from the others I found.

Comment: I've never seen an encoding problem when using Oracle from Java. Never ever. This problem does not seem to exist. Most likely, the problem occurs when producing the HTTP response. If it doesn't specify a character set or the wrong one, then the browser might assume a different one and misinterpret the HTTP response.

Comment: I'm sorry @Codo, maybe I did not express myself correctly. There are a lot of oracle+java encoding problem when the installation use, for example ISO instead of UTF-8. Some examples:

Comment: Some example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553483/oracle-java-encoding-problem-while-insert or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771890/oracle-encoding-problems or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229890/geting-utf-8-character-issue-in-oracle-and-java